# loops and switches in c my code

Tags: c

Below is  my code. I'm wondering how the value of `i` is incrementing by itself? At the end of the iteration the value of `i` becomes 10; as it's not satisfying the loop condition it has to come out of the loop and when it does the value that's getting printed is 11. How is that even possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<10;i++)
  {
    switch(i)
    {
      case 1: i=i+2;
      default : i=i+3;
    }
  }
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: when does the loop break?

Comment: I recommend learning about loops in your favorite C reference, textbook, or tutorial.

Comment: For loops are executed as this pseudo code: `i=1; loop: if not (1<10) goto end; { /* body */ } i++; goto loop; end:`. The machine code generated from a for loop will look something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 places where `i` is changed (after the initialization to 1)

Check the comments in order A, B, C, ...

```
int main()
{   
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<10;i++)
             // ^^ 6 -> 7 (end of 1st loop)          C
             // ^^ 10 -> 11 (end of 2nd loop)        E
  {
    switch(i)
    {
      case 1: i=i+2;     // 1 -> 3 (1st loop)        A

      default : i=i+3;   // 3 -> 6 (1st loop)        B
                         // 7 -> 10 (2nd loop)       D
    }
  }
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

So it's the `i++` that makes `i` change from 10 to 11 before `i` is printed.

Remember that

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    code
}
```

is equivalent to

```
i=1;
while(i<10)
{
    code

    i++;  // Notice: The increment is before the i<10 condition is checked
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add additional printf to show the value of `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<10;i++)
  {
    printf("before switch: %d\n",i);
    switch(i)
    {
      case 1: i=i+2;printf("case 1: %d\n",i);
      default : i=i+3;printf("default: %d\n",i);
    }
  }
  printf("finished: %d\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
before switch: 1
case 1: 3
default: 6
before switch: 7
default: 10
finished: 11
```

note that after `default` the next value is incremented

Comment: I did something similar  but my Q is why i's  increasing like after default it goes up and as 10<10 is not true so i can't increase right? so 10 should be printed?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your code

```
default : i=i+3;
```

increments i by 3, and i steps up from 7 to 10 to 11 which is also failing the condition in

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
```

hence loop terminates and leaves i at 11.
Also it should be noticed that after executing Case 1 first time i is incremented at two places as listed above.

As per the code value of i goes up like 1-->6-->7-->10-->11.

> Now the question is why actually it goes up from 10->11.

This is because in `for(i=1;i<10;i++)` second and third statements `i<10;i++` executes every time even when the `i<10;` condition fails. This is how actually `for` loops works. In other words `for loop's` third statement `i++` executes just when the loop body ends at `}` of loop body.

Comment: bro you saying that  I'll step up from 8 to 11 but i can never be 8 bro

Comment: 1-->6-->7-->10-->11. Actually this is how it goes up. Edited the answer. It is going from 1 to 6 because there is no break in case 1.

Answer (score 0):

Value of ***i*** is *11* because of ***i++***.
Try using ***while*** loop instead of ***for*** as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i=1;
   while(i<10)
   {
      switch(i)
      {
         case 1: i=i+2;
                 printf("case 1: %d\n",i);
                 i++;

         default: i=i+3;
                  printf("default: %d\n",i);
      }
   }
   printf("finished: %d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```